# keyReleased is not executing code

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, keylistener

I am using a keyReleased to enable or disable a jbutton if two jtextfields  are empty or not empty.  I have placed some print line statements in the method to see the boolean values as the method executes. The statements never print leading me to believe that the method is not being executed.  The jbutton is supposed to start disabled until text is entered into both Jtextfields and then the jbutton is enabled.

```
CalculateButton.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)
        {
            // the two jtextfields being checked for length
            boolean first = ipAddress.getText().length() > 0;
            boolean secoundnd = borrowedBits.getText().length() > 0;

            // print statements of the boolean values
            System.out.println("IpAddress " + first);
            System.out.println("borrowedBits"  + secoundnd);


            // if statements checking to see if the button should be enabled 
            or disabled after each key press. 
            if (ipAddress.getText().length() > 0 && borrowedBits.getText().length() > 0)
            {
                CalculateButton.setEnabled(true);;

            }

            if (ipAddress.getText().length() == 0 || borrowedBits.getText().length() == 0)
            {
                CalculateButton.setEnabled(false);;

            }




        }
```

Comment: add the key listener to the textfields not the button. If it's disabled the method won't get called.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variables are correct and some are not. Be consistent and learn from examples you find in books, tutorials etc.

Answer (score 2):

> The jbutton is supposed to start disabled until text is entered into both Jtextfields and then the jbutton is enabled

Here is an example using a `DocumentListener` that is far more flexible then coding if/else statements for every text component. This solution is more generic and works for any number of text fields.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DataEntered implements DocumentListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    public DataEntered(JButton button)
    {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void addTextField(JTextField textField)
    {
        textFields.add( textField );
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener( this );
    }

    public boolean isDataEntered()
    {
        for (JTextField textField : textFields)
        {
            if (textField.getText().trim().length() == 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        checkData();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    private void checkData()
    {
        button.setEnabled( isDataEntered() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JButton submit = new JButton( "Submit" );
        submit.setEnabled( false );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(10);

        DataEntered de = new DataEntered( submit );
        de.addTextField( textField1 );
        de.addTextField( textField2 );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textField1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(textField2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(submit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the button is disabled when a key is released then the method still won't be called. You need to attach the `KeyAdapter` to both of the textfields which remain enabled.

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)
        {
           ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually he needs to add it to *both* textfields.

Comment: @GergelyBacso whoops, that's what I intended to say but I guess my fingers typed something else. I made the edit. Thanks!

Comment: wrong answer - ActionListener is designated to be used for JButton, and logics should be to add DocumentListener to both JTextFields,

Comment: @mKorbel Could you further explain? Using `KeyListener` on my computer produces the desired results.

Comment: @Dando18, it may work, but Swing has newer and better API's to use which are better than a KeyListener. See my answer for an example.